# My gridview does not display.

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, gridview

I am creating a web part on SharePoint that shows site owners and their email addresses. I am able to show that information in a listbox, but I would rather do it in a gridview. When I change my code to display the info in a gridview, the gridview does not display.

Here is the code I have:

```
namespace DisplaySiteOwnersVWP.VisualWebPart1
{
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{

    string mySiteURL = "my Site URL goes here";
    DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();


    public VisualWebPart1()
    {
    }


    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dtTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Email");

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(mySiteURL))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPGroup ownerGroup = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;

                if (ownerGroup != null)
                {
                    foreach (SPUser user in ownerGroup.Users)
                    {
                        if (user.IsSiteAdmin == true)
                        {
                            DataRow dtRow = dtTable.NewRow();
                            dtRow["Name"] = user.Name;
                            dtRow["Email"] = user.Email;
                        }
                    }
                }

                gvOwners.DataSource = dtTable;
                gvOwners.DataBind();

            }
        }

    } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

After

```
dtRow["Name"] = user.Name;
dtRow["Email"] = user.Email;
```

Write

```
dtRow.update();
```

Well, speaking more broadly, whenever you make a change to a list item, make sure you cal the update method to actually make the changes to the list item.

Comment: I get the red squiggly under the word update. Intellisense doesn't pick it up. The error says "System.Data.DataRow does not contain a definition for 'update' and no extension 'update' accepting a first argument of type System.Data.DataRow could be found"

Comment: Yeah, just looked at the function again, seems to only work on a list item.  Give me a bit, and I'll see if I can dig anything else up :)

Comment: I'm guessing gvOwners is a formfield you created somewere else?

Comment: Yes. I have it in the .ascx file like this: <asp:GridView ID="gvOwners" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on the .databind method you are using.  There is .AddDataBinding for a method call, and there is ddrwt:DataBind in an aspx page, but I think you are confusing the two here.

Comment: I've been searching on google and every page I've been to, the suggestion was to have .databind

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358034/is-there-a-good-reference-sharepoints-databinding-syntax  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.adddatabinding.aspx  This is all I can find on the subject.  If you can point me to the resource that you use, I will take a look at it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/225196/asp-GridView-not-visible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288800/gridview-in-asp-net-is-not-displaying-with-or-without-data

Comment: I'm not sure why you aren't getting any error messages though.  According to http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_databinding.asp  there are only certain objects you can call .dataBind on.  Instead of the GridView object, try creating one of the permitted objects, and then attach that to the GridView.  Here is another link to help http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_arraylist.asp

Comment: I solved my problem. I added the line dtTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);